# Do I need an embedded system, custom os, or embedded os?

Tags: operating-systems, embedded, assembly

I have been toying around with the idea of developing a "kiosk" for in-home users that may or may not have knowledge of computers or how to use them. For sake of argument lets say my "kiosk" is similar to a point of sale (POS) device you would find at a grocery store or the electronic menus restaurants are starting to use. However unlike some POS devices, I would like to turn on the device and immediately execute the software without using a traditional operating system or input device (remember the end users may not be tech savvy - if something goes wrong they should be able to reboot the device and restart the application - without dealing with searching for and starting an additional application).

At minimum the system needs a color screen with touch capabilities, wireless Internet capabilities, and USB support for various devices such as printers. So my question is what is the best way to achieve this? Am I looking at:

1. Developing a custom OS
2. Running a bare version of Linux and somehow booting straight into an application.
3. Using an embedded OS such as Windows Embedded.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coding an OS is out of the question, unless you have a team of pretty good developers a big budget and a lot of time.

Using Linux distros, MS embedded or MS normal OS is the path to go. Here is a bit info :

Here’s a list of some distros with kiosk mode support.

```
Porteus kiosk
The mini distro Porteus has a dedicated mod to support kiosk mode. Provides options to customize as need on first boot.
Instant WebKiosk
Boots from USB key and browser only.
Can Bike OS
Puppy based live-CD OS with a web browser and little else.
SanicKiosk
Turn-key web kiosk designed for public libraries, city government, health clinics, and other institutions in need of public information stations. It is intended for easy installation and administration by users with minimal technical knowledge.
Ubuntu Guest login
Normal Ubuntu installation allows guest access from the login prompt. A perfect solution for kiosks. Login into guest mode with restricted permissions but non-restricted browser. Works from USB too.
Scientific Linux 6 and CentOS 6
Both the distros can be configured into kiosk-mode automatically by running this script.
Webconverger (Unconfigured edition)
Runs from USB, easy management console, highly secure, privacy conscious & fool-proof. No vendor lock-in, malware-free & firewall included. The Unconfigured offering is perfectly usable and free of cost.
justbrowsing
A bootable Linux “Live CD” that does not make any changes to the existing operating system on the computer. You can use the browser of your choice. Bundled webapps include a calculator, text editor, timer and more. Settings can be saved to a USB drive.
```

[Building KIOSK with Ubuntu](http://thepcspy.com/read/building-a-kiosk-computer-ubuntu-1404-chrome/)

[Set up a kiosk on Windows 10 Pro, Enterprise, or Education](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt219051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 for the ubuntu kiosk link. I didn't know I could do this so easily. This will be good for the prototype. If it catches on I can hire my developers ;)

Comment: Hope your project is a success. Once it goes off the ground come back to show it.

Answer (score 1):

I would say no to **1**. There is no need for you to develop a custom OS.

I would go with option **2** or **3**.

Personally I would go with option **2** & setup the boot script to open the application and 'lock-in' the user on startup.

You could also use option **3** if you prefer something pre-made and/or commercial.